# Passing struct to function without typing every member (C++ no pointers)

Tags: c++, function, struct, parameters

So I think more of the inexperienced programmers will be roaming around with this question. I can pass a struct to a function successfully like the snippet below:

```
void printMonster(MonsterStats slime, MonsterStats spider, MonsterStats orc, MonsterStats ogre, MonsterStats dragon, int charLevel)
```

However you could imagine if the struct MonsterStats had 120 members which all needed to be passed to printMonster my code will become absolute spaghetti!
So the question is, how can I pass this struct into my function without typing every single member into the function parameter?

For inquiries about how much I "should" know about c++ at this point, I have arrived at the [learncpp.com chapter 4 comprehensive quiz](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/4-x-chapter-4-comprehensive-quiz/). I went a little out of scope of the assignment but I've done nothing I shouldn't be able to do by now.

full below (working but lengthy):

```
#include <iostream>


struct MonsterStats
{
    std::string type;
    std::string name;
    int health;
    int level;
};



void printMonster(MonsterStats slime, MonsterStats spider, MonsterStats orc, MonsterStats ogre, MonsterStats dragon, int charLevel)
{

    if(charLevel>=slime.level&&charLevel<spider.level)
        std::cout << "This " << slime.type << " is named " << slime.name << " and has " << slime.health << " health.\n";
    else if(charLevel>=spider.level&&charLevel<orc.level)
        std::cout << "This " << spider.type << " is named " << spider.name << " and has " << spider.health << " health.\n";
    else if(charLevel>=orc.level&&charLevel<ogre.level)
        std::cout << "This " << orc.type << " is named " << orc.name << " and has " << orc.health << " health.\n";
    else if(charLevel>=ogre.level&&charLevel<dragon.level)
        std::cout << "This " << ogre.type << " is named " << ogre.name << " and has " << ogre.health << " health.\n";
    else if(charLevel>=dragon.level)
        std::cout << "This " << dragon.type << " is named " << dragon.name << " and has " << dragon.health << " health.\n";
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    MonsterStats ogre{"Ogre","Grumble",345, 16};            //Type, Name, Health, Level
    MonsterStats dragon{"Dragon","Spyro", 890, 21};         //Type, Name, Health, Level
    MonsterStats orc{"Orc","Rakanishu", 165, 11};           //Type, Name, Health, Level
    MonsterStats spider{"Giant Spider", "Arachnid", 80, 6}; //Type, Name, Health, Level
    MonsterStats slime{"Slime", "Blurp", 35, 1};            //Type, Name, Health, Level

    std::string getChoice="y";
    int charLevel;
    cout << "Please enter the level of your character to proceed to battle: ";
    cin >> charLevel;
    if(charLevel>0)
    {
        while(getChoice=="y")
        {
            printMonster(slime, spider, orc, ogre, dragon, charLevel);

            cout << "Do you want to fight the monster? (y/n)";
            cin >> getChoice;
            if(getChoice=="y")
            {
                cout << "You destroyed the monster and gained an experience level!\n\n";
                charLevel+=1;
            }
            else
                cout << "You ran like Forest Gump and got out of the fight safely!\n\n";
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "Please create a character in order to play the game.";
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the answers :)

Comment: Passing `MonsterStats` once should be sufficient. I don't get your concerns? Its completely unclear what you're actually asking about.

Comment: If I was doing this, I'd probably pass an array of `MonsterStats`, sort the array by "level", increment through the array until I hit a monster with a higher level than the PC, then use the previous monster to pull data / strings from. Or something like.

Comment: I think you're using the word "members" in a confusing way. In C/C++, members are the fields in a struct or class, such as `type`, `name`, `health`, and `level` in the `MonsterStats` struct.

Comment: @user2475059 It's C++, so I'd use a `std::vector<MonsterStats>`.

Comment: Re-reading, I'd probably not pass it as an array; instead I would basically do the array process as I said, then pass the single `MonsterStats` that I'd selected for printing.

Comment: @Barmar same difference; it's not something that really needs to be focused on here, since it's clear they need to grasp passing / using / designing a program with containers first, before they get into the finer points of container selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you tend to call "members" (e.g. `ogre`, `spider`, etc...)  are in fact instances of the `MonsterStats` structure.  So variables.

In C++, the "members" are the variables or functions that are in the structure (e.g.`name`, `health`, `level`, etc...).

Of course, using many instances like in your snippet, and retype a lot of time the same things would be a nightmare. Fortunately, in chapter 5 you'll see the loops and in chapter 6 you'll learn about arrays and vectors to handle a bundle of instances.

This would look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct MonsterStats
{
   ...
};
...
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    vector<MonsterStats> monsters { 
                            {"Ogre","Grumble",345, 16}, 
                            {"Dragon","Spyro", 890, 21}, 
                            {"Orc","Rakanishu", 165, 11}, 
                            {"Giant Spider", "Arachnid", 80, 6}, 
                            {"Slime", "Blurp", 35, 1} }; 

    ... 
    printMonster(monsters, charlevel); 
    ...
}
```

And you would then access to the `i`-th item with `monsters[i]`.

Comment: Okay that seems clear! Thanks alot for the quick response, I will wait patiently for me to pass Ch5 to improve on my progam then. PS: does this thread mark as solved automaticly after x-amount of days? Or do I click something in here?

Answer (score 0):

Once you start using a standard library container you could make use of the standard library to sort and search:

```
void printMonster(std::vector<MonsterStats>& monsters, int charLevel)
{
    MonsterStats mystats{"","",0,charLevel};
    auto comp = [](const auto& i, const auto& j) {return i.level <= j.level; };
    std::sort(monsters.begin(), monsters.end(), comp);
    auto monster_iterator = std::lower_bound(monsters.begin(), monsters.end(), mystats, comp);
    auto monster = *(monster_iterator - 1);
    std::cout << "You have level " << charLevel << '\n';
    std::cout << "This " << monster.type << " is named " << monster.name << " and has " << monster.health << " health.\n";
}
```

Here is the [full program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/032505fee51e58f7):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct MonsterStats
{
    std::string type;
    std::string name;
    int health;
    int level;
};

void printMonster(std::vector<MonsterStats>& monsters, int charLevel)
{
    MonsterStats mystats{"","",0,charLevel};
    auto comp = [](const auto& i, const auto& j) {return i.level <= j.level; };
    std::sort(monsters.begin(), monsters.end(), comp);
    auto monster_iterator = std::lower_bound(monsters.begin(), monsters.end(), mystats, comp);
    auto monster = *(monster_iterator - 1);
    std::cout << "You have level " << charLevel << '\n';
    std::cout << "This " << monster.type << " is named " << monster.name << " and has " << monster.health << " health.\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<MonsterStats> monsters{
        {"Ogre","Grumble",345, 16},            //Type, Name, Health, Level
        {"Dragon","Spyro", 890, 21},           //Type, Name, Health, Level
        {"Orc","Rakanishu", 165, 11},          //Type, Name, Health, Level
        {"Giant Spider", "Arachnid", 80, 6},   //Type, Name, Health, Level
        {"Slime", "Blurp", 35, 1}};            //Type, Name, Health, Level

    std::string getChoice = "y";
    int charLevel;
    std::cout << "Please enter the level of your character to proceed to battle: ";
    std::cin >> charLevel;
    if(charLevel>0)
    {
        while(getChoice == "y")
        {
            printMonster(monsters, charLevel);

            std::cout << "Do you want to fight the monster? (y/n)";
            std::cin >> getChoice;
            if(getChoice == "y")
            {
                std::cout << "You destroyed the monster and gained an experience level!\n\n";
                charLevel += 1;
            }
            else
                std::cout << "You ran like Forest Gump and got out of the fight safely!\n\n";
        }
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Please create a character in order to play the game.";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer and I will definately look into it in the future! However, I do not quite understand what you did in void printMonster there yet for it is way out of scope of what I've learnt so far. None the less thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: My pleasure. I'm also still learning and I was trying different ways to do the same thing and so I thought I would share anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner program might be with a [multiset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) (sorted container) using a custom comparator.

The comparator could have this form:

```
struct myComp {
    bool operator()(const MonsterStats& i, const MonsterStats& j) {
        return i.level < j.level;
    }
};
```

And the multiset could use it:

```
using myMultiset = std::multiset<MonsterStats, myComp>;
```

Then, searching can be simpler as the set is already sorted:

```
auto& monster = *--monsters.upper_bound(mystats);
```

Printing could use the `<<` operator:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MonsterStats& monster)
{
     std::cout 
         << "Monster has level: " << monster.level << '\n' 
         << "This " << monster.type << " is named " << monster.name << " and has " << monster.health << " health.\n";
     return os;
}
```

Full program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

struct MonsterStats
{
    std::string type;
    std::string name;
    int health;
    int level;
};

struct myComp {
    bool operator()(const MonsterStats& i, const MonsterStats& j) {
        return i.level < j.level;
    }
};

using myMultiset = std::multiset<MonsterStats, myComp>;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MonsterStats& monster)
{
     std::cout 
         << "Monster has level: " << monster.level << '\n' 
         << "This " << monster.type << " is named " << monster.name << " and has " << monster.health << " health.\n";
     return os;
}

int main()
{
    myMultiset monsters{
        {{"Ogre","Grumble",345, 16},            //Type, Name, Health, Level
        {"Dragon","Spyro", 890, 21},           //Type, Name, Health, Level
        {"Orc","Rakanishu", 165, 11},          //Type, Name, Health, Level
        {"Giant Spider", "Arachnid", 80, 6},   //Type, Name, Health, Level
        {"Slime", "Blurp", 35, 1}}};            //Type, Name, Health, Level

    std::string getChoice = "y";
    std::cout << "Please enter the level of your character to proceed to battle: ";
    MonsterStats mystats{};
    std::cin >> mystats.level;
    if(mystats.level>0)
    {
        while(getChoice == "y")
        {
            auto& monster = *--monsters.upper_bound(mystats);
            std::cout 
                << "You have level " << mystats.level << '\n' 
                << monster
                << "Do you want to fight the monster? (y/n)";
            std::cin >> getChoice;
            if(getChoice == "y")
            {
                std::cout << "You destroyed the monster and gained an experience level!\n\n";
                ++mystats.level;
            }
            else
                std::cout << "You ran like Forest Gump and got out of the fight safely!\n\n";
        }
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Please create a character in order to play the game.";
    return 0;
}
```

Or, if you include the `operator<` in the struct then you can simplify even further:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

struct MonsterStats
{
    std::string type;
    std::string name;
    int health;
    int level;

    bool operator<(const MonsterStats& rhs) const {
        return level < rhs.level;
    }
};

using myMultiset = std::multiset<MonsterStats>;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MonsterStats& monster)
{
    std::cout
        << "Monster has level: " << monster.level << '\n'
        << "This " << monster.type << " is named " << monster.name << " and has " << monster.health << " health.\n";
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    myMultiset monsters{
        {{"Ogre","Grumble",345, 16},            //Type, Name, Health, Level
        {"Dragon","Spyro", 890, 21},           //Type, Name, Health, Level
        {"Orc","Rakanishu", 165, 11},          //Type, Name, Health, Level
        {"Giant Spider", "Arachnid", 80, 6},   //Type, Name, Health, Level
        {"Slime", "Blurp", 35, 1}}};            //Type, Name, Health, Level

    std::string getChoice = "y";
    std::cout << "Please enter the level of your character to proceed to battle: ";
    MonsterStats mystats{};
    std::cin >> mystats.level;
    if(mystats.level>0)
    {
        while(getChoice == "y")
        {
            auto& monster = *--monsters.upper_bound(mystats);
            std::cout
                << "You have level " << mystats.level << '\n'
                << monster
                << "Do you want to fight the monster? (y/n)";
            std::cin >> getChoice;
            if(getChoice == "y")
            {
                std::cout << "You destroyed the monster and gained an experience level!\n\n";
                ++mystats.level;
            }
            else
                std::cout << "You ran like Forest Gump and got out of the fight safely!\n\n";
        }
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Please create a character in order to play the game.";
    return 0;
}
```